# Showing the winding number of the unit circle is $1$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

1. Let $\gamma$ denote the unit circle parameterized on the domain $[0,2\pi]$.
2. I'm trying to compute $n(\gamma, 0)$ as follows:

   $$
   n(\gamma,0) = {1 \over 2\pi i}\int_\gamma {dz \over z} = {1 \over 2 \pi i} \int_0^{2 \pi} {1 \over \gamma(t)} \gamma'(t)\ dt= \underbrace{\ldots}_{\text{?}} = 1
   $$
3. As flagged above, I'm not sure what justifies the inference to the answer of $1$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because $\gamma(t)=e^{it},\;t\in[0,2\pi]$.
Hence
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\gamma'(t)}{\gamma(t)}\,dt
=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{ie^{it}}{e^{it}}\,dt=1$$

Comment: You should write explicitly the path! ;-)

Comment: I don't think he should/must/would, @Joe. Whoever's doing complex analysis but cannot understand the parametrization of the unit circle *should*, perhaps, go back to the basics in geometry. Nice answer. +1

Comment: @DonAntonio thank you!